# Let $(R,m)$ be * local and $R_m$ regular. Is R regular?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, graded-rings, regular-rings

Let $(R,m)$ be *local and $R_m$ regular. Is $R$ regular?

Comment: What does *local mean?

Comment: Let R be a graded ring. A graded ideal m of R is called
$*$maximal, if every graded ideal that properly contains m equals R. The ring R is called $ *$local, if it has a unique $ *$ maximal ideal m . A $ *$local ring
with $ *$maximal ideal m is denoted by (R,m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $R_p$ is regular for every graded prime $p$ (why?) and this is true since $R_P=(R_m )_{pR_m}$.